# How do I change the parent element using the values of nested Components in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, routes

I would like to change the value in AudioPlayer whenever the value of CurrentSong changes so that the song changes in AudioPlayer every time I play a new song.
in Song.js, I have

```
const phoneContextValue = useContext(PhoneContext); 
phoneContextValue.SetCurrentSong(props.flink);
```

where props.flink is the link to the audio. I want the AudioPlayer to be changed whenever Song.js is called.

AudioPlayer.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import PhoneContext from '../../../others/PhoneContext';

const AudioPlayer = () => {
  const phoneContextValue = useContext(PhoneContext);
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(phoneContextValue.CurrentSong);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAudio(phoneContextValue.CurrentSong);
  }, [phoneContextValue.CurrentSong]);

  return (
    <>
      <audio className='audio-song' controls src={audio} alt='Audio Player'>
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

I tried to do this using useEffect but the AudioPlayer was not getting updated when the CurrentSong changed.

RouterPage.js:

```
const RouterPage = () => {
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [CurrentSong,SetCurrentSong]=useState('');
  const phoneContextValue = {
    phone,
    setPhone,
    CurrentSong,
    SetCurrentSong,
  };
  
  return (
    <PhoneContext.Provider value={phoneContextValue}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/home_page" element={<AudioPlayer />}>
          <Route path="/home_page" element={<MainFooter />} >
            <Route index element={<MainPageHome />} />
            <Route path="library" element={<MainPageLibrary />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="song/:value/:name" element={<Song/>} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </PhoneContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default RouterPage;
```

I tried to use useEffect in AudioPlayer but it didnt update the value

Comment: Please share all the code snippets involved in this starting from song.js

Answer (score 0):

In your case you dont need to declare another state or side effects in AudioPlayer , just pass the context of CurrentSong to audio element:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import PhoneContext from '../../../others/PhoneContext';

const AudioPlayer = () => {
  const {CurrentSong}= useContext(PhoneContext);

  return (
    <>
      <audio className='audio-song' controls src={CurrentSong} alt='Audio Player'>
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

When CurrentSong changes , source of the audio will also change.
Also console.log the CurrentSong to check if it actually changes or not